# Compare elements in array for similarity js

Tags: javascript

I have an array for example

`var a = [1,4,6,1,1,1,1];`

and I need to compare each element in array for similarity. If all of them are similar I need return `true`, if one or more of them are different it should return `false`

Will be glad to get the answer.

Comment: What do you mean by 'similar'? Equal? All within certain bounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one method to achieve it, by using `Set`.

```js
var a = [1,1,1,1];
var b = [1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3];

function check(arr) {
  console.log([...new Set(arr)].length == 1 ? true : false);
}

check(a);
check(b);
```

Comment: @Vasyl Kozhushko Would be cool if you would upvote my answer (:

Answer (score 1):

if they all need to be the same then you could just check to see if everything in the array is equal to the first element by using `filter` and `length`. The length of the array filtered by any element in the list should equal the original length.

```js
const a = [1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1];

function similarity(arr) {

  let firstItem = arr[0];

  return arr.filter(elements => elements == firstItem).length != arr.length ? false : true;
}


console.log(similarity(a));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the `every` Method.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

> The every() method tests whether all elements in the array pass the
>   test implemented by the provided function.

```js
var notsimilar= [1,4,6,1,1,1,1];
var similar= [2,2,2];
console.log(notsimilar.every((x,i,a) => a[i] === a[0]));
console.log(similar.every((x,i,a) => a[i] === a[0]));
```